# 10$ registration bonus on Coinbase : how to get it?

Tags: wallet, coinbase.com

I found the picture below and I registered on Coinbase with this signup bonus link :

[bonus-coinbase.com](http://bonus-coinbase.com) :

[image: picture I found yesterday on the web]

I didn't received the 10$ bonus yet.

When will i get it ?
Is there something I have to do to get it?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: That's obviously not legitimate, it has a troll face smoking in it. Not sure if you're trying to be funny or just...

Comment: @MeshCollider I found the picture on a Facebook fanpage about bitcoins. The link is correct but I don't know if i just have to wait or do something to get the bonus

Comment: @MeshCollider it's legitimate. If you go to bonus-coinbase.com it redirects you to coinbase.com/join (to where you can't get to if you don't actually visit bonus-coinbase.com). It's just a promotion offer to get people to join Coinbase. Please do your research before coming to conclusions. It took me 30 seconds to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it : you get the bonus when you buy or sell 100$ of bitcoins, ethers or litecoins on Coinbase.

:)